# ComboBox option disappears when selected

Tags: sql, ms-access, combobox, listbox

I have a ComboBox of States that populates a ListBox of cities when selected.

I added an option of (all) using a Union query in the ComboBox that successfully populates all of the cities in the ListBox, but it leaves the ComboBox blank after it's selected. I want "(all)" to stay in that ComboBox.

The row source for the States ComboBox is:

```
SELECT tblStatesProvince.ID, tblStatesProvince.LngState
FROM tblStatesProvince
UNION Select Null as AllChoice, "(all)" as Bogus From tblStatesProvince
ORDER BY tblStatesProvince.LngState;
```

The row source for the Cities Listbox is:

```
SELECT tblCities.ID, tblCities.City, tblCities.State
FROM tblCities
WHERE (((tblCities.State)=[Forms]![frmCities].[cboSelectState])) OR ((([Forms]![frmCities].[cboSelectState]) Is Null))
ORDER BY tblCities.City;
```

Comment: You might consider replacing the Null value, as even Null is not equal to Null, something like -1 (given that tblStatesProvince.ID is likely a numeric) and then adjust the WHERE statement to OR ((([Forms]![frmCities].[cboSelectState]) = -1))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suspect that the use of `NULL` in the original `SELECT` statement is the root cause of the problems. NULLs are really just placeholders for values and not comparable to (typical) data types, such as strings or numerics.  `NULL` does not have a data type.

I would rewrite the two statements as follows (assuming that `tblStatesProvince.ID` is a numeric), which removes `NULL` from the comparisons:

```
SELECT tblStatesProvince.ID, tblStatesProvince.LngState
FROM tblStatesProvince
UNION Select -1 as AllChoice, "(all)" as Bogus From tblStatesProvince
ORDER BY tblStatesProvince.LngState;

SELECT tblCities.ID, tblCities.City, tblCities.State
FROM tblCities
WHERE (((tblCities.State)=[Forms]![frmCities].[cboSelectState])) OR ((([Forms]![frmCities].[cboSelectState]) = -1))
ORDER BY tblCities.City;
```